# What am I missing out on when using msbuild to deploy?

Tags: iis

I'm trying to use msbuild/webdeploy with teamcity to deploy to IIS. However, I'm getting an ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED error message and link pointing me to [this page on iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED).

I'm using the Web Management Service to do this and I can verify that the username and password exist (I can log into the server with that combination), the site exists and the the user has IIS manager permissions:

[image: Image showing manager permissions]

So what am I missing out?

**Edit**: New screenshot to answer @dirt:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right there in your screen shot: "*The server is configured to accept connections only from accounts with Windows credentials.*".

**Main level IIS Manager > Management Services > Allow both Windows and IIS Credentials**

Reference: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7

Also make sure you have added the user to both the Server level IIS Manager Users and the Site level IIS Manager Permissions:

Server level:
[image: Server level]

Site level:
[image: Site level]

And finally check this page: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes

```
ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
Diagnosis - This error code can surface because of a number of different reasons. It typically indicates an authentication or authorization problem, and can happen because of any of thee following reasons:
User does not exist
User does not have IIS Manager access to site if connecting using Web Management Service
Site does not exist
Password is incorrect
Resolution - If connecting using the Web Management Service:
Verify that the username and password are correct
Verify that the site exists
Verify that the user has IIS Manager Permissions to the site's scope
Resolution - If connecting using the Remote Agent Service:
Verify that the username and password are correct
Verify that the user account you specified is a member of the Administrators group on the remote computer. NOTE: If you are not using the built-in administrator, create a new group called the "MSDepSvcUsers" group and add your new administrator to that group.
Verify that the site exists
```

Comment: That is a windows user. I haven't got any iismanager users on that box

Comment: Also, enabling both types of users doesn't help.

Comment: Are you adding the user at the top IIS Server level or at the Site level? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753695(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I am adding a windows user

Comment: I added screenshots; the user needs to be configured at both server and site IIS Manager levels

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what I see in IIS Manager Permissions at a server level. I have added the user in at a site level.

Comment: Check this page: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes

Comment: That's the link in my original question

Comment: Is the Windows User you are using a member of the Administrators group?

Comment: It wasn't but I've added it in and it didn't do anything. Just as an aside, teamcity is on one machine and IIS is on another. The username and password that I'm passing over is one that is on the IIS server.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out with a windows user @PiersKarsenbarg?

Comment: No and I've moved on from that employer since then. Having said that, I've done the same and had it working so I'm guessing there was something iffy going on with the domain.